# How to set up path alias with jsconfig in node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I just came up with a problem that jsconfig only works in my client folder by not the server folder. Here is my config file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "commonJS",
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/node_modules/*"]
}
```

When I import user.js from server/controller/user.js with this:

```js
import UserCtrl from 'controller/user';
```

It shows "Error: Cannot find module 'controller'". I used to solve this with a package named babel-module-resolver. It does work but this doesn't have any IntelliSense when I was typing the path. So I want to handle this with jsconfig as my client does. Can you help me with this? I would be very glad if anyone can solve this problem for me.

Here is my project structure:
[image]

Comment: Firstly, image that you have attached is not visible.

Comment: Now, tell me what do you want to import? is user controller is a file?

Comment: @Harshal Strange... I can see it from my browser and my colleague can either see it with his account. You can try to refresh this page to see whether it shows.

Comment: @Harshal Of course, dude. My absolute path is right. I used to solve this with a package named babel-module-resolver. It does work but this doesn't have any IntelliSense when I was typing the path. So I want to handle this with jsconfig as my client does.

Comment: Have you tried adding something like ```*paths*? " "@/*":["src/*"] ```

Comment: @Harshal Yes. And this only works in my client folder. Each of my client folder and server foler has a jsconfig file.